# how to set background image in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to set my  background image on my first view could you please tell me why my background image not display .I want to display background image on my view .i tried to use css but not work 
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvYdNM

```
  .test {
     border: 1px solid red;
     position: relative!important;

background: url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1*AJALCafqXhfLMG7iF7Ho0A.jpeg');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to override the default style you need to use `!important`, remove relative positioning

```
.test {
     border: 1px solid red;
     background: url('some-url.jpg')!important;
    background-size:cover !important;
    }
```

further apply this test class to  tag and remove from header tag

see [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgeOPw)

Comment: it is working you are getting half of the image the upper portion

Comment: @ab I need to add background in whole view ...background image of header , contend ,footer

Comment: @Shruti you should ask the question properly .

Comment: @A.B  sorry I think you don't get my Question .Actually first check my image .image url in which a person is diving.I need that image on my background  .Actually my header and footer  is display so I need to add image only on contend side

Comment: thie url i provided is sample url, you will need to replace it with yours

Comment: in you demo or url there is no image in output

Comment: @Shruti strange, reopen the demo link may be you are seeing the previous version, i have updated the link also